# jstree create_node event is not firing but able to create the node?

Tags: jquery, jstree

I'm able to create the node but the event is not firing. No errors reported in firefox. What I'm doing wrong...

```
     $("#treeFile1").jstree("create", null, "outside", { "attr" : { "rel" : "folder" }}).bind("create.jstree", function(event,data)
                    {
                            alert("hello");
                    });
```

As I mention, the node (folder) is created with no problems. The event is not firing....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Connect the bind to the tree container directly, like this:

```
   $("#treeFile1").bind("create.jstree", function(event,data)
   {
            alert("hello");
   });
```

Comment: This is a pretty relevant answer, since it seems that only a few select events can be captured when the listeners are bound to the jstree instance.